# How to use strdup with user input?

Tags: arrays, c, string, strtok, strdup

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    
    char cipher[5][5] = {
                    {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'},
                    {'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'k'},
                    {'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p'},
                    {'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u'},
                    {'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'}
                        };
                    
    
    char cm;
    char *original;
    char *portion;
    printf("Enter ciphered message: ");
    scanf("%s", &cm);


    original = strdup(&cm);
    portion = strtok(original, "-");

    
    while (portion != NULL){

        int i = portion[0]-'0';
        int j = portion[1]-'0';

        printf("%c", cipher[i][j]);
        portion = strtok(NULL, "-");
        
        }
    

    return 0;
}
```

Hello, I'm a new computer science student and I'm already having a problem. I'm writing a polybius cypher and I can't seem to get the user input saved correctly to use at strdup

With input i.e.: 00-11-22-33-44 I should receive "agntz" but I can't get it to print. I'm new here so I apologize if I haven't formatted my question correctly.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &cm);` - you are trying to read a string into a single character variable.

Comment: @CompuerScienceNoob,  Try `char cm;....  scanf("%s", &cm);` --> `char cm[100]; ....  scanf("%99s", cm);`.

Comment: Consider not using `strtok()`.  It doesn't look like you particularly need it, and if you don't use it then it doesn't look like you would have any need for `strdup()` either.  Not that I see the point of the `strdup()` itself in the code presented.  If indeed you don't have any further use for the ciphertext after you've deciphered it, then probably you don't need to read the whole thing in one go in the first place - you ought to be able to process the input 1-2 characters at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you `char cm` is a single character but you want to read a string `char *cm`.  If your `scanf()` supports the optional `m` character then the easiest option to have it allocate your string for you:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char cipher[5][5] = {
        {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'},
        {'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'k'},
        {'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p'},
        {'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u'},
        {'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'}
    };
    char *cm;
    char *original;
    char *portion;
    printf("Enter ciphered message: ");
    scanf("%ms", &cm);
    original = strdup(cm);
    portion = strtok(original, "-");
    while (portion != NULL){
        int i = portion[0]-'0';
        int j = portion[1]-'0';
        printf("%c", cipher[i][j]);
        portion = strtok(NULL, "-");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

and the you are now getting the expected output:

```
Enter ciphered message: 00-11-22-33-44
agntz
```

It would be a good idea to check that portion[0] and portion[1] are indeed numbers (for instance by using`isdigit()`) to avoid out of bound access of `cipher`.  Also check that you only get two digits in portion (`strlen(portion) == 2`).

Is missing `j` in the cipher on purpose?

You can refactor the above along these lines:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char cipher[] = "abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char *cm;
    printf("Enter ciphered message: ");
    scanf("%ms", &cm);
    for(char *portion = strtok(cm, "-"); portion; portion = strtok(NULL, "-")) {
        int i = portion[0]-'0';
        int j = portion[1]-'0';
        printf("%c", cipher[5*i+j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```